# spark mapPartitionRDD can't print values

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark

I am following the Machine Learning with Spark Book and trying to convert the python code to scala code and using Beaker notebook to share variables in order to pass values to python to plot with matplotlib as described in the book. Most of the code so far I have been able to convert but I am having some issues with the `try-catch` conversion with data cleansing with the `u.item` dataset. Below code ends in a infinite loop without a clear issue what the error is.

```
val movieData = sc.textFile("/Users/minHenry/workspace/ml-100k/u.item")
val movieDataSplit = movieData.first()

val numMovies = movieData.count()

def convertYear(x:String):Int = x.takeRight(4) match {
         case x => x.takeRight(4).toInt
         case _ => 1900
    }

val movieFields = movieData.map(lines => lines.split('|'))
print(movieData.first())
val years1 = movieFields.map(fields => fields(2))

val years = movieFields.map(fields => fields(2).map(x=>convertYear(x.toString())))
val filteredYears = years.filter(x => x!=1900)
years.take(2).foreach(println)
```

I suspect my problem is with my pattern match but I am not exactly sure what's wrong with it. I think the `takeRight()` works because it doesn't complain about the type that this function is being applied to.

*UPDATE*

I have updated the code as follows, per advice from the answer provided thus far:

```
import scala.util.Try
val movieData = sc.textFile("/Users/minHenry/workspace/ml-100k/u.item")

def convertYear(x:String):Int = Try(x.toInt).getOrElse(1900)
val movieFields = movieData.map(lines => lines.split('|'))

val preYears = movieFields.map(fields => fields(2))
val years = preYears.map(x => x.takeRight(4))//.map(x=>convertYear(x))
println("=======> years")
years.take(2).foreach(println) //--output = 1995/n1995
println("=======> filteredYears")
val filteredYears = years.filter(x => x!=1900)

filteredYears.take(2).foreach(println)
//val movieAges = filteredYears.map(yr => (1998-yr)).countByValue()
```

I commented out the `map` following the `takeRight(4)` because its easier to comment than putting `x=>convertYear(x.takeRight(4))` and should produce the same output. When I apply this `convertYear()` function i still end up in an infinite loop. the values print as expected in the few print statements shown. The problem is if i cannot remove the data point that cannot be easily converted to Int then I am unable to run the `countByValue()` function in the last line.

Here is the link to my public beaker notebook for more context:
https://pub.beakernotebook.com/#/publications/56eed31d-85ad-4728-a45d-14b3b08d673f

Comment: What is your `convertYear` method supposed to do?

Comment: Apparently there was one erroneous data point so it replaces that with a hard coded value of 1900 and then later this value is removed entirely. The format of the field being transformed by this function is "Jan-15-1988" or a similar date value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `movieData: RDD[String]`
2. `movieFields: RDD[Array[String]]`
3. `years1: RDD[String]`
4. `val years = movieFields.map(fields => fields(2).map(x=>convertYear(x.toString())))` - `fields(2)` is `String` and so `x` is `Char`, because `String` is treated as `Seq[Char]`. All inputs to `convertYear(x: String)` have only one letter string.

Your error is types incompatability hiding (`convertYear(x.toString())`). It's alarm bell. Always use type system in scala, don't hide problem with `toString()` or `isInstanceOf` or something else. Then compiler shows error before running.

P.S.

1. Second call of `takeRight` is useless.
2. `def convertYear(x:String):Int = x.takeRight(4) match {
        case x => x.takeRight(4).toInt
        case _ => 1900
   }`

Pattern matching is about checking type or conditions (with if statement). Your first partial function doesn't check anything. All inputs go to `x.takeRight(4).toInt`. Also there is no defence against `toInt` exception.
Use instead `def convertYear(x: String): Int = Try(x.toInt).getOrElse(1900)`.

**Update**

```
scala> import scala.util.Try
import scala.util.Try

scala> def convertYear(x:String):Int = Try(x.toInt).getOrElse(1900)
convertYear: (x: String)Int

scala> List("sdsdf", "1989", "2009", "1945", "asdf", "455")
res0: List[String] = List(sdsdf, 1989, 2009, 1945, asdf, 455)

scala> res0.map(convertYear)
res1: List[Int] = List(1900, 1989, 2009, 1945, 1900, 455)
```

With RDD all the same, because it is a functor as List.

`val filteredYears = years.filter(x => x!=1900)` Wouldn't work as you expect. `x` is a String not Int. Scala doesn't implicitly convert types for comparision. So you always get `true`.